# MethodOverride not working with DELETE request

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've managed to upload files to my postgres database but I'm unable to implement the delete request.

**My delete function in the controllers**

```
 static async deleteFile(req, res) {
        try {
            const { file_id } = req.params;
            await FileModel.RemoveFile(file_id);
            return res.redirect('/documents');
        } catch (err) {
            return res.send(err.message);
        }
    }
```

**My route**

```
router.delete("/documents/:file_id", tokenExists, userAccess, FileContainer.deleteFile);
```

**My .ejs file**
From this file, I want to execute the delete request. It contains a table that displays all the documents in my database. So, I want to click on a trash icon and delete that specific row from my back-end and client.

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-dark mr-auto ml-auto" id="fileTable">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Uploaded On</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% data.forEach(file => {  %>
                <tr>
                    <td class="file-title"><a href="documents/<%=file.file_name%>"
                            download="<%=file.file_name%>"><%=file.file_name%></a></td>
                    <td><%=file.file_type%></td>
                    <td><%=file.uploaded_at%></td>
                    <td>
                        <form id="deletingForm" action="/documents/<%=file.file_id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" onsubmit="deletingForm()">
                            <input class="fa fa-trash" type="submit" id="deleteFile" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**What I tried and what's really happening**

I tried sending the above request but  I'm getting the *Method Not Allowed!* error. Please somebody help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `method="POST"` i.e. you are actually sending a POST request not a DELETE request.

i.e. your request is actually

`POST /documents/n?_method=DELETE HTTP/1.1`

not

`DELETE /documents/n?_method=DELETE HTTP/1.1`

What you would need to do is use JavaScript, jQuery, etc to send a actual DELETE request. As an aside, having a verb in the URL `_method=DELETE` is not a good idea at all.

To fix I'd remove the form and simply call your `deletingForm` method directly from a click on your `deleteFile` input to make the DELETE request via ajax or some such. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/documents/' + fileId,
    type: 'DELETE',
    ...
});
```

However you are going to run into a further issue in that you are assigning an ID to the input element in a loop - but IDs must be unique - i.e. you can't have multiple elements with the ID `deleteFile`

EDIT:

> To use a query string value to override the method, specify the query
> string key as a string argument to the methodOverride function.

```
var express = require('express')
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
var app = express()

// override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
```

see: https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Comment: is it possible to access the data that I'm trying to work within <script> tag? I tried it in vain. And you say that ```_method=DELETE``` is not good at all yet that's how method-override works. I'd appreciate some more guidance.

Comment: I had already used the *over-ride* package but forgot to use to the post http request in express. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If form method is `POST` then use `req.body`